# @Html adjusting size of icons

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

How to change the size of a Textbox in ASP.NET MVC Razor engine?

```
@Html.TextBox("Name")
```

I know how to change in html but this is something new for me

Comment: Just add a class name and use css to style it (and what does _icons_ have to do with the question?)

Comment: You can always use inline styling - `@Html.TextBox("Name",new { style = "width:100px;" })` but its not recommended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HTML attributes

```
@Html.TextBox("Name", new { @class = "class-name" })
```

and in your CSS file

```
.class-name {
    width: 50px;
}
```